# How to parse the data returned by the HTTP request RPC (state_getmetadata)?

Tags: metadata

https://github.com/emeraldpay/polkaj

[image]

I request the RPC method state through the method provided by the SDK linked above_ GetMetadata, but metadata cannot be resolved. There will be an error (unsupported metadata version: 14). How can I solve it? Preferably Java. Thank you in advance for helping my friends

Answer (score 1):

The library that you are using seems to be outdated. For what I have seen there is an open issue for this, I would just suggest you to track it there - https://github.com/emeraldpay/polkaj/issues/88